# Subgrids only show 2 rows on Form / White space increases with each update of Form

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

The subgrids on my Form are set to Number of Rows: 250, and Automatically expand to use available space is checked.

This works fine for a short time, and the subgrids do dynamically size themselves.

However, ANY time new customizations are published, the subgrids go back to showing only 2 rows and some white space is added after the subgrid.  Over time, the whitespace appears to increase.  When I go back to the Form editor, the section containing the subgrid is all wonky looking (extra spaces under the subgrid).  If I check the properties of the subgrid, they still show as indicated above.

As I understand it, this was to have been resolved with Rollup 17.  The rollup download page indicates this as one of the bugs that were fixed: Removing / Adding any field to the form after enabling the option "Automatically expand to use available space" causes the sub grid to shrink or resize to much smaller in size.

However, the problem persists (and it's the most frustrating thing ever!)

Does anyone know how to resolve this?  Alternatively, does anyone know how I can contact Microsoft to inform them of this issue without them charging me for a solution?

Answer (score 0):

If memory serves this happens when more than one SUBGRID , IFRAME or TEXTAREA are set to automatically expand although only a single auto expand element is allowed / supported.
You need to reset all element with auto expand Save , Publish and then set the SUBGRID with auto expand again.

[Dynamics CRM - Thinking outside the BOX](http://totbcrm.blogspot.com/) 
HTH